Power BI: How to pivot column without nulls added?
I want to pivot a column but Power BI adds nulls.
I selected the column 'Question' and selected 'pivot column' then selected 'Response' with no aggregation but Power BI added nulls.  Is there a way to prevent this?  I spent the whole day on this and I am sure there this a simple solution.  Thanks for your help in advance.


If you drop/remove the Category column before the Pivot then you can avoid the nulls since all the other columns have the same value for each pair.


Is there a way to avoid this end result? Is there a pivot selection I should use instead?  Fill Up and down are for excel  I am using power BI.

Fill Up and Fill Down is also available in Power BI Power Query. Ultimately you have 2 rows per record and there isn't a pivot option to avoid the nulls. I'll update the answer with alternatives if you want to avoid using Fill Up and Fill Down. Can we assume CategoryType is the ID for a suggestion-score pair?

I tell a lie. If you drop the Category column before the pivot then you won't get the nulls. Essentially, if all the other columns have the same values for each pair then nulls are avoided.

Your solution to delete Category first before pivoting the column 'Question' using the 'Response' with no aggregation worked!  I spent the entire day searching online for solutions.   Thank you so much for taking the time from your busy day to help a stranger.
